# UIView.isHidden not working when changing orientation using viewWillTransition

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation, viewwilltransitiontosize

I'm trying to change orientation with just one view, the rest are anchored to Portrait. I've set a method in my AppDelegate as below

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if globalVariables.gIsDosageView == "Y" {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all;
        } else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait;
        }
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait;
    }
}
```

The global variable gIsDosageView is set to "Y" when the Dosage view is selected. I've created two separate views, portraitView (375x812) and landscapeView (812x375). I've used the viewWillTransition method to catch each change in orientation as below

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if size.width < 400 {
        self.userImg.isHidden = false
        self.deviceImg.isHidden = false
        self.portraitView.isHidden = false
        self.landscapeView.isHidden = true
    }
    else {
        self.userImg.isHidden = true
        self.deviceImg.isHidden = true
        self.portraitView.isHidden = true
        self.landscapeView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

When I go from the main screen to Dosage it displays the correct screen and will toggle between both orientation views without issue. However, if I go to another screen and come back to the Dosage screen it only shows the screen that was first loaded in both orientation screens. I've stepped through the code and it hides the right screens but this is not reflected in the resulting view. If I select the screen in portrait first, it will toggle successfully between portrait and landscape but if I go to the next screen and return to Dosage, it will only show the Portrait screen regardless of orientation and appears to ignore the code in viewWillTransition().

Why is this and what have I missed?

Comment: You aren't calling `super.viewWillTransition(to:size, with:coordinator)`. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition) mentions this as a necessary step.

Comment: viewWillTransition is called whenever the orientation changes, which is what I want, so I don't need to call it. The problem is that when it is called the views aren't hiding as they should in the code

Comment: Also, have you checked you are setting the UI in main thread?

Comment: Yes, I added a Dispatch.main.async() block to my code and the result was the same

Comment: I think if you change `globalvariables.gIsDosageView` when you leave Dosage, you need to set it back to “Y” in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewWillTransition` is only called when the device is rotated. When you switch between open views without rotating, it won't get called, so won't set the view up how you want it. Try putting the test in `viewWillAppear` instead.

Comment: Not quite true - it's also called when the app is resized (for e.g. in the multitasking view of an iPad).

Comment: You're right, but it isn't called when there is a segue between view controllers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If the device isn't rotated the views are ok, the problem arises when the device is rotated. For instance if the portrait view is visible and I rotate the view to landscape, instead of making the landscape view visible and hiding the portrait view, the portrait view remains visible and doesn't fit the landscape view.

Comment: It was a combination of Pranav's answer and adding the logic to ViewWillAppear that solved the issue. Thank you both for your help

Comment: No problem. Glad you fixed it.